# How can I find the nearest intersection of a given address using iOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, location

I got the user location, now I want to, somehow, identify the nearest intersection/cross.
For example: I'm at 5th Av. between the 44 & 45. The Mapkit will give me the 5th av as the current address but I can't find a way to detect the two intersections.

Is this possible?

I'm not stuck to the map kit, and the only thing I want is a method or class to return the name of the streets. So if there is another service or kit to determine that, it will be perfect.

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

[_geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
    {
        _currentPlaceMark = [placemarks lastObject];
        _posicaoAtual.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@-%@",
                              [_currentPlaceMark valueForKey:@"thoroughfare"],
                              [_currentPlaceMark valueForKey:@"locality"],
                              [_currentPlaceMark valueForKey:@"administrativeArea"]];
    }
} ];
```